# Compare 2 sql tables for data that does not match

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a sql table Company1 with fields companyname,personname,mobile,cardno (which was imported from excel file) and another table Company2 with more fields including the same fields as above (added from form).

I want to check for a particlular company how may rows are missing from each table and how many mismatches are there. Like any row in company2 not present in company1 and if present are the personname,mobileno and cardno matching for a particular row.

For eg. 
if Company 1 has row

```
Peter,9412686,10239897
```

and Company2 has

```
Peter,9000000, 10239897
```

there is a mismatch of mobile no. I want to show the rows which have mismatches for correction. Is it possible with sql query.

Comment: Assuming company1 table has all records only for that company, is the company name column redundant?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a `LEFT JOIN` from `Company2` to `Company1` with the join condition that all 4 (or more) columns match.  Then, a mismatch would occur when a record in `Company2` does not exactly match a record in `Company1`.

```
SELECT c2.*
FROM Company2 c2
LEFT JOIN Company1 c1
    ON c2.companyname = c1.companyname AND
       c2.personname  = c1.personname  AND
       c2.mobile      = c1.mobile      AND
       c2.cardno      = c1.cardno
WHERE c1.companyname IS NULL
```

This assumes that `Company2` is the master table with regard to entries for employees working for a given company.  If an employee record could be present in one, but not both, tables then you should consider using a full outer join instead.

Comment: whether the above query will hold good if OP wants to know the exact column names of the columns where in the row value mismatches?

Comment: @Coder1991 No, it won't, but the OP didn't ask for this explicitly.  What you are contemplating might require dynamic SQL.  My answer would at least flag mismatches.

Comment: Yes. I was just curious to know that. Apart from dynamic sql, my assumption is merge operation will also let the OP know about the mismatched values (output.deleted), if in case OP needs to know the exact column names. However that would be a costly operation i hope.

Comment: @Coder1991 My _hope_ would be that the number of mismatched records is small, and that defects in the data is a relatively rare event, such that manual inspection would be a possibility.

Comment: Does the above query show all mismatches or those which are matching. 
Please note that Company 1 table which is imported from excel is the latest and I need to check Company2 data against the first table.

Comment: Yes, this will show only mismatches, and it will consider every record in the `Company2` table (though not necessarily in the `Company1` table).  If you need to check both tables at the same, then you can consider the other answer given.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? In the current version of the query, mobile mismatch overrides cardno mismatch, But it shouldn't be difficult to add that too.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(C1.personname,C2.personname) personname,
CASE 
    WHEN C1.personname IS NULL THEN 'Missing in Company 1 table' 
    WHEN C2.personname IS NULL THEN 'Missing in Company 2 table' 
    WHEN (C1.mobile <> C2.mobile) THEN 'Mobile mismatch'
    WHEN (C1.cardno <> C2.cardno) THEN 'Cardno mismatch'
    ELSE NULL
END AS 'Comment' 
FROM 
Company1 C1
FULL OUTER JOIN
Company2 C2 ON C1.personname = C2.personname
```